# Unable to train images using LBPHFaceRecognizer and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition

Currently, I am working on training the images for facial recognition system. I am using Python, OpenCV for doing so. I have collected the samples from the webcam, however, the size of sample images differs. The example for the size of sample images is 376 x 376, 412 x 412, 836 x 836.

The screenshot of current working directory:

[image]

The sample images are saved within the main folder named 'sampleImgFolder' and under the main folder specific folder for each sample.

[image]

---

Source code for training image

---

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
targetImagesDirectory="sampleImgFolder/"
dataset = cv2.CascadeClassifier('resources/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

def getImageWithID(path):
    #empty list to store processed data 
    sampleFaces = []
    sampleFaceId = []

    os.chdir(targetImagesDirectory)
    for directory in os.listdir():
        os.chdir(directory)
        for files in os.listdir():
            imagePath = '{}/{}'.format(os.getcwd(), files)

            imagePil = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')
            imageNumpy = np.array(imagePil, 'uint8') #conversion of normal image to numpy array
            #imageNumpy.astype(np.float32)

            #detect face 
            faces = dataset.detectMultiScale(imageNumpy)

            #extracting id from file name
            id = files.split('_')
            id = id[0].split('-')
            id = id[2]

            for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                sampleFaces.append(imageNumpy[y:y + h, x:x + w])
                sampleFaceId.append(id)

        os.chdir('../')
    os.chdir('../')   

    return np.array(sampleFaceId), sampleFaces
print("reading images")
Ids,faces=getImageWithID(targetImagesDirectory)
print('reading completed')
recognizer.train(faces,Ids)
print("training")
#train the dataset. Create a file name trainningData.yml
recognizer.write('train/trainningData.yml')
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am getting following error while running above code:

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am getting the same error right now :(

Answer (score 0):

That is because the datatype of Ids is a list[str]. .train() methods accepts int for labels